# App stopped when trying to use image button but works fine with just button

Tags: android, mobile

I am new to android development. I am in the process of developing a small app. My home page has a background and 6 image buttons. When I try to load my app on emulator, the app crashes. But when I try to use just buttons and remove background, the app seems to work fine. Please guide me as to how can I use image buttons in my app or is there any other way to use images as buttons.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/android_button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Read This. It Will Work Perfectly [ImageButtonDocumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed or clicked by the user. By default, an ImageButton looks like a regular Button, with the standard button background that changes color during different button states. The image on the surface of the button is defined either by the android:src attribute in the XML element or by the setImageResource(int) method.

To remove the standard button background image, define your own background image or set the background color to be transparent.

To indicate the different button states (focused, selected, etc.), you can define a different image for each state. E.g., a blue image by default, an orange one for when focused, and a yellow one for when pressed. An easy way to do this is with an `XML drawable` "selector." For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Save the XML file in your project `res/drawable/` folder and then reference it as a `drawable` for the source of your `ImageButton` (in the `android:src attribute`). Android will automatically change the image based on the state of the button and the corresponding images defined in the XML.

The order of the elements is important because they are evaluated in order. This is why the "normal" button image comes last, because it will only be applied after `android:state_pressed` and `android:state_focused` have both evaluated false.

Then create a button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:bacckground="@drawable/android_button" />
```

the replace `android:bacckground="@drawable/android_button" />` with your drawable image as `android:bacckground="@drawable/you_drawable_image" />`